# Seting a hyperlink below an image

Tags: android, hyperlink

I wanna set hyperlink below my image in my activity. e.g, when i click on hyperlink then the new activity  should open

my Main.java file

```java
>package com.a.test;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.net.Uri;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.TextView;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class Main extends Activity {  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    }
}
```

main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/product"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="192dp"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:contentDescription="@string/test"
android:gravity="center"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:src="@drawable/img9" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Brand Name: Dolce and Gabbana"
android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:text="  Color: Light Green"
android:textColor="#000000" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Product Name: Hand Bag"
android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="310dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="  Price: $599.89"
android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the text of the TextView that should contain the link to the following :

```
 SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(context , NewActivity.class));
    }
};
text.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, 0); 
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(text);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(text, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

notice that "start" and "end" are the respective indices of the portion of the string that you want to make as a link.